# Android MVVM - How to pass data to viewmodel with big form in view?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

I have a view which contains some widgets and after the user clicks "save" this information is sent to the `SomeViewModel`. The problem is that when I collect the information from the view this result in a 10+ arguments method in the `SomeViewModel`.

On the other hand I can create the `SomeDataClass` inside the view and pass it to the `SomeViewModel` which I think its not good because the view shouldn't know about it. Is there any other alternatives?

```
class SomeViewModel : ViewModel() {

    fun newItem(text1: String, text2: String, item1: Int, item2: Int, ...) {
        ...
    }

    fun newItem(someDataClass: SomeDataClass) {
        ...
    }

}

class SomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private fun newItem() {
        someViewModel.newItem(
            edittext1.text.toString(),
            edittext2.text.toString(),
            spinner1.selectedItemId,
            spinner2.selectedItemId,
            ...
        )
    }

}
```

Comment: ViewModel is used to store UI related data in lifecycle conscious way, I don't believe you should be using widgets in your ViewModel.

Comment: I dont have widgets in my ViewModel

Comment: You could argue it's a UX issue, in that the user shouldn't have to fill so much in all on one page :-). But actually both of your options are right, you could make a data class called `FormViewInput` and unpack it again straight away - but whats the point that'll be more wasted lines of code. I would be ok with the `newItem` method taking a lot of parameters here. The important thing is to pack it up into a proper representation of some Type when moving it around your model. (Also if you used databinding for MVVM, you wouldn't be having this discussion).

Comment: I appreciate your answer @Blundell